# Condition statement producing same result despite inputting different value

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making an app. I am using if/else if through javascript. Based on the codes stored previously like an amount and a comment based on the amount. eg More than 500 = Expensive, 200-499 = OK, Below 199 = Cheap. I would then key in an amount like eg 400 and it would then do if/else if statement. However, right now, my outputs are all "Expensive" when although I put 400 (which should have been "OK" in this situation. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you in advance! c;

```
if (Greaterequal >= Toamount) {
        advising = Greaterequalcomment
    }
    else if ((Betweenone >= Toamount) && (Toamount >= Betweentwo)) {
        advising = Betweencomment
    }
    else if (Lessthanequal >= Toamount) {
        advising = Lessthanequalcomment
    }

    $("#Converting").empty();
    $("#Converting").append("My advice is as follows: " + advising);
});
```

Comment: Probably you are doing string comparison, try with `parseInt`

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak hello! I did use parseInt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing "Expensive" all the time because of "if (Greaterequal >= Toamount)" this condition.

Try this::

```
if (Toamount >= Greaterequal) {
        advising = Greaterequalcomment
}else if ((Toamount >= Betweenone) && (Toamount <= Betweentwo)) {
        advising = Betweencomment
}else {
        advising = Lessthanequalcomment
}


$("#Converting").empty();
$("#Converting").append("My advice is as follows: " + advising);
```

Comment: um hello! They are displaying both greaterequalcomment and lessthanequalcommen but not the betweencomment :(

Comment: It is working @my end. Please check with the Betweenone and Betweentwo values once again. Betweenone should be lesser value and Betweentwo should be greater value.

Comment: oh yea it is now

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Greaterequal >= Toamount) {
    advising = Greaterequalcomment
} else if ((Betweenone >= Toamount) && (Toamount >= Betweentwo)) {
    advising = Betweencomment
} else {
    advising = Lessthanequalcomment
}

$("#Converting").empty();
$("#Converting").append("My advice is as follows: " + advising);
```

There was a "(" in your if-Statement.
You can suggest if the IF and ELIF conditions are not hitting that its less.
I hope i could help.